# Android is not receiving information sent via UDP

Tags: android, sockets, udp

I am trying to obtain information with the usage of UDP protocol on my Android device. I have to consider two cases - connection via access point, and router.
Sadly, in case of access point, I am loosing 95% of data - even though the sending process works properly (I can easily receive that information on my laptop). Somehow Android just can not cope with high traffic sent from one source. 
Such problem does not exist when the connection works via router, because then the data is broadcasted from multiple sources, and it works reliably.

I would really appreciate any information about the cause of such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue - the access point did not detect any device in his network, even though there were few android devices connected. I had to write a pinging service, that keeps the constant outbound traffic.